# What Solution (sandboxed and farm) should be select= Farm Solutions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

What context, advantage and disadvantage should I be aware of in my mind when I gonna select farm or sandboxed solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandboxed solutions is depricated in SharePoint 2013, and should be avoided. Depricated in this context means that it won't be supported in the next version of SharePoint. So **the answer to your question** is simple: **always use farm solutions**.

However, there are other things to consider when developing for SharePoint 2013: Apps. That may be another angle to your questions, and a lot of answers to that are already given on the Microsoft Technet Wiki [SharePoint 2013: What to Do? Farm Solution vs Sandbox vs App](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13373.sharepoint-2013-what-to-do-farm-solution-vs-sandbox-vs-app.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Sandbox solutions are deprecated, but will be here for a while (SharePoint Apps require it to work for instance).

If your business requirements allows you to create a SharePoint App - that us your first option.

If you can't go for an App or a Farm solution you still can use Sandboxed solutions. The important thing here is that you should only deploy declarative elements in the Sandboxed Solution, at all cost avoid Sandboxed solutions with code/assemblies.